# Need help to understand the steps to the solution $(2/3)^x=6/25$ using complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Trying to understand the specific steps of the solution to $(2/3)^x=6/25$

whose solution is $$x = {\log(25/6) - 2i\pi n \over\log(3/2)}$$ with $n \in \mathbb Z$

and real solution $$x= {\log(2)+\log(3)-2\log(5) \over \log(2)-\log(3)}$$

I get it that you get $x=\log(6/25)/\log(2/3)$ from $(2/3)^x=6/25$ but I don't get the complex element of the solution.

Comment: Rewrite it as $\exp(x\log(2/3))=6/25$ and use that $\ker(\exp)=2\pi i \Bbb Z$.

Comment: ... i.e. $\exp(x\log(2/3))=\exp(\log(6/25))$.  That can then be $\exp(x\log(2/3))=\exp(\log(6/25)+2i\pi n)$ since $\exp(2i\pi n)=1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the question can be rewritten as $(2/3)^{x}=e^{x\log(2/3)}=e^{\log(6/25)}$. Now here it is important to see that the complex exponential is $2\pi i$ periodic. So $e^{x+2\pi in}=e^x\;\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $e^{x\log(2/3)+2\pi in}=e^{\log(6/25)}$ holds as well. If we rearrange this equation we have: $e^{x}=e^{(\log(6/25)-2\pi in)/\log(2/3)}$. And you can conclude that $x=(\log(6/25)-2\pi in)/\log(2/3)\;n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The period is $2\pi i$, not $2\pi$

Comment: Thank you! A small typo :)